# Disable Firefox image zoom via javascript

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, zooming

I have a problem with image quality in Firefox: Firefox seems
to zoom "everything" per default so some images really look 
fuzzy while in chrome their quality is perfect! 
I found out, that there is a setting in Firefox, which resolves the problem:

> "View->Zoom->Zoom Text only".

Do you know a way to force Firefox to use this setting for a special 
website (using javascript)??

Thanks a lot
Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because that's a setting for users, who may have poor eyesight and want to actually see the images on your site. It's not for you to make that decision on their behalf.

Comment: ok.. seems as if we have to accept this circumstance, thanks for your comment