# How do I make resolution ok

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, slider, cycle

Here is a [demo](http://html-playground.netne.net/razvy/fun/) for my page.

I use jQuery cycle plugin for a slider and I make the photos full height and witdh.

When I zoom the page the picture doesn't stay at the same resolution only when i refresh the page.

[image: Exemple]

How can I make the picture stay at the same resolution when I zoom not after refresh?

Comment: first why do you need zoom?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you need but can be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser

Comment: This behavior is there because you have fixed the height and width of the image.

Comment: I make this website for a client I want to make it responsive. And this is a bug..

Comment: @Razvan you need a resposive slider for this

Comment: And what can I do to make the slider responsive?

Comment: @Kamo thanks! It work. I put zoom: reset; and is now ok!

Answer (score 1):

I use

> zoom: reset;

and is working!

Thanks @Kamo

Comment: Where I can do this. is the first time when I use stackoverflow.

Comment: When you hover the comment which helped, there is an arrow on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you have mentioned as to zoom which you are trying to control by scripting is not ideal, as this will take effect only when the browser refreshes but not on your client size zoom.

To achieve this, you need to use a `background-size:cover;`

You can read more about the same **[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images)**

In order to user this, you need to remove images from your code and add them as a `background-image` via a CSS Class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: he uses img tags not css background

Comment: I agree, but he has to remove it to use background to achieve what he wants. Shall edit this in my answer.

Comment: edit it if you want i don't think he knows what responsive truly means