# Completely disable the zoom functionality in the browser, including buttons and menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help to find a solution for disabling the browser zoom in/out in all possible ways.

I have found this code snippet, which works perfectly in the way it was designed for:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '61' || event.which == '107' || event.which == '173' || event.which == '109'  || event.which == '187'  || event.which == '189'  ) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This perfectly blocks <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> and the wheel, but is there any way to also disable the browser's built-in control panels or context menus?

[Browser's control panels http://screenshot.cz/NPRTD/browsers-panels.png](http://screenshot.cz/NPRTD/browsers-panels.png)

Comment: You can disable the context menu with by doing `return false` on the `oncontextmenu` event. But you cannot disabled the control panels that the browser has. [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser)

Comment: Impossible! You cannot control that, it is browser functions and you have no control over it. If I want to zoom, well you cannot stop me! :)

Comment: you can do it for **mobile** with the viewport meta tag, setting "user-scalable=0".. sounds that that's what your looking for, but for desktop.  [Detecting zoom level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) might be somewhat relevant.