# prevent or disable zooming in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to disable zoom in ng or javascript? Probably I need some events if the user trys to zoom with the mouse or with the keyboard.

I want to make some UX - tests so I need this.

thx in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser

Comment: thx for the link this was very helpful for me