# Prevent percentage resize after page load

Tags: html, css, resize, width, window-resize

I was wondering if it was a way to prevent resizing after the page has loaded. I have a header coded like this:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0% auto;
}
```

Can I prevent the width from resizing after the page has loaded, so that if someone zooms or resize their webpage, the header will remain at the 100% it was set to when the page was loaded?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use some JS to set the width of the header element to a specific width so that re-size and zoom do not affect it.

Here is a jQuery solution using [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

```html
<div>
  <header class="to-fixed">Header</header>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```js
var $to_fixed = $( '.to-fixed' );

$to_fixed.width( $to_fixed.width() );
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w9psx3t7/1

What happens here is we use JavaScript to tell us how wide the element is in pixels when it is at 100% width. Then we apply that width directly to the element via the `style` attribute. The `width()` method of jQuery allows us to retrieve and set the element's width. Since the width is set directly on the element it will override the default width value set by the CSS.

Notice that once the page has loaded the our JS has set the value and when you re-size the `<header>` element maintains it's width.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean prevent the user from zooming in, then that's answered here: [Prevent zoom cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser)

And if you want to stop users from resizing their browser window (and generally keeping it the same size at all times) you can do something like:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    window.resizeTo(width, height);
});
```

Both are these are advised against though. I can't really see why you'd want this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in CSS if you're setting the width to `100%`. The simple way to do this in Javascript would be doing the following on page load:

```
var width = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].offsetWidth;
document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].style.width = width;
```