# How to prevent scaling on touch screen != mobile

Tags: javascript, html

Am running a web app on touch screen computer where you can zoom in and out. I want to prevent this behaviour I added this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, width=device-width" />
```

Which is work fine on mobile devices but not on computer touch screen.

Added info: with the meta tag above I can also zoom in when use a mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent zoom cross-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser)

Comment: Answers not working.

Comment: Doesn't the answer state that this behaviour is not standard nor supported by browser vendors? In other words, doesn't the answer state that you can't achieve what you've trying to?

Comment: Yes, there was no way to workaround it.

Answer (score -1):

Try `user-scalable = no` instead of `user-scalable = 0`.