# How to force web page zoom at 100% ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I want set zoom of my page at 100% and i dont want to user can change that. I have tried some css function and js but couldn't find a proper way. I already search my question in here.

Comment: So you want to alter the zoom of the browser, is that correct?

Comment: You can refer this question [Prevent zoom cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser)

Comment: This can make your page inaccessible for people who depend on zoom to actually be able to read the content on your page. Do you really want to exclude them?

Comment: This isnt my own poject, product owner wants this way.

Comment: @Arty even if it is not your project, you should explain to the product owner that this would be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [detect-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-zoom). 
Once installed, in your componenet you can try

```
import detectZoom from 'detect-zoom';

handleZoom = () => {
    if (detectZoom.device() * 100 !== 100) {
      console.log('your zoom is not 100)
    } else {
      console.log('your zoom is 100)
    }   
 }
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateZoom();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateZoom);
}
```