# How to disable Zooming my website on Computer (using Ctrl + scroll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, viewport

i want to make my website not zoomable. Like when i press Ctrl+Scroll most websites would zoom by % but i want to disable it.
Do you guys have any solution or idea how to make it possible ? I saw a page where i cant zoom, he is it : https://layouts.b3multimedia.ie/free-divi-layouts/finance/

Thanks for any advice. <3

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent zoom cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser)

Comment: non of these solutions helped me :P

Comment: You say it doesn't help you but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31131948/1145388) appears to have exactly what want.

Answer (score -1):

You can enter a special `meta` tag called the meta viewport tag into your `head` tag like so:

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scaleable=no">
</head>
```

to prevent people from zooming into your page. Note the `user-scaleable=no` bit.

However, some browsers automatically override that. In fact, you should avoid disabling zooming in any case, as it creates an accessibility issue (as [A. Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth) mentioned in the comments).

Comment: Be wary of using this as on some systems it still prevents zooming (though IOS since version 10 ignores it for pinch zoom I think it may still be there for some Android browsers). This creates an accessibility issue which should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for that, and sorry for the (extremely) late response, but I have updated the answer accordingly.